# drRacket code assistance

Tags: scheme, racket

I have this codes:

```
(define (make-entry person money job)
     (list person money job))
(define (make-person list)
(define (sampledata
     (list (make-entry (make-person "jerry" "nicolas") 100 "clerk")
            (make-entry (make-person "shara" "vi") 50 "singer")))
(define trial-person (make-entry (make-person "jerry" "nicolas") 100 "clerk")
```

my problem is that I don't know what function could I use so I would result to:

```
(name trial-person); 
Value: (jerry nicolas)
(money trial-person)
;Value: (100)
(job trial-person)
;Value: (clerk)
```

I did some readings but still I have not yet come up with an answer. It would be good if someone could help me so I could be able to participate in class. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On the second `define` you are defining a procedure `make-person` that takes the argument `list` and it never ends. If you were using DrRacket and pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> you'd see the strange identation this makes:

```
(define (make-person list)
  (define (sampledata
           (list (make-entry (make-person "jerry" "nicolas") 100 "clerk")
                 (make-entry (make-person "shara" "vi") 50 "singer")))
    (define trial-person (make-entry (make-person "jerry" "nicolas") 100 "clerk")
```

You see that you have a local procedue definition inside the definition of the procedure `make-person`. Using `list` as an argument will make the procedure `sampledata` never work since it uses `list` as a procedure but will use whatever you passed instead. `sampledata` also has a local definition `trial-person` but since neither of the procedures have a body all of them would result in syntax errors even if you add ending parentheses to the end.

An educated guess I guess the code should have been like this:

If the implementation of `make-person` does the same as `list` it should be:

```
(define make-person list) ; removed ( before make.person
(define sampledata        ; removed ( before sampledata
  (list (make-entry (make-person "jerry" "nicolas") 100 "clerk")
        (make-entry (make-person "shara" "vi") 50 "singer")))
(define trial-person (make-entry (make-person "jerry" "nicolas") 100 "clerk")) ; added missing ) at end
```

Now since you formatted the code as if the code was properly written it is almost impossible to see any mistakes or the difference so I commented the changes. Pressing  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> often will save you a lot of time.

As for the question about how to make `name`, `money`, and `job`: If you evaluate `trial-person` you get `(("jerry" "nicolas") 100 "clerk")` thus if you know your `car` and `cdr` it should be clear that the definition for `money` would be the same as the procedure that fetches `100` from that list, which is `cadr`.